# AngularJS filter of events in my calendar

Tags: angularjs, filter

I will filter the events of the calendar in my application and I have tried it with the expression at the bottom but it failed at compilation time.
Has anyone a hint how I can do it right.
The calendarEvent- objects look like this:

[image: calendarEvent]

```
<mwl-calendar
            view="vm.calendarView"
            view-date="vm.calendarDate"
            events="vm.calendarEvents | filter:vm.selectedUser.id == vm.calendarEvents.userId"
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter should look more like this:

```
<mwl-calendar
        view="vm.calendarView"
        view-date="vm.calendarDate"
        events="vm.calendarEvents | filter:{userId: vm.selectedUser.id}">
```

Please [review the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for more information.

[Here is a plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/q6re4vmH7p45lYeNaqRM)

Comment: I get the following fault: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig. Does anyone know how I can prevent this?

Comment: I added a plunker demo of the basic filter by `userId` string.

Comment: It looks like that **<mwl-calendar ...*** can not really work with filter. I wroter a filter but now I get teh following fault: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=vm.calendarEvents%20%7C%20calendarFilter:vm.selectedUser&p1=mwlCalendar

Comment: That makes sense if `mwl-calendar` has data-binding like `scope: {events: '='}` because the filter result would be read-only.  To solve that, you would need to use the filter service in your controller like `vm.filteredEvents = $filter('filter')(vm.calendarEvents, {userId: vm.selectedUser.id})`.  You would need to put that in a function that you call from a `$watch('vm.selectedUser.id')` and whenever `vm.calendarEvents` gets set.  And then in template use `<mwl-calendar events="filteredEvents">`

Comment: Alternatively (if you have access to), you could modify `mwl-calendar` directive so that it does not data-bind its `events` attribute.  Instead you could do like: `attr.$observe('events', function(events){ scope.events = events; });`